# View is not showing all columns

Tags: views, users

I configured a View showing all groups the user belongs to. I also added the name of the author and his/her role.
In the Preview of the View everything is OK, the same if Im logged as an admin (user1). 
But if Im logged as an authenticated user, the view is not showing up the Role column.

Any ideas what can be wrong? Maybe some permissions, but which one?
[image: img1]
[image: img3]

Answer (score 1):

I think, Role data is not displayed to users other than administrator.
Try with 'Field Permissions' module to edit the field specific permissions.